# DataTable issue. AddData is not firing from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Let me say i.e I added every plugin possible.

Question is On-load of page the data coming and sitting well on table but when I click on add button to add some row, The Add functionality in the Controller not firing. Don't know WHY.

MY view code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   debugger;
   $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
       "bProcessing": true,
       "bServerSide": true,
       "sAjaxSource": 'Home/AjaxHandler',
       "sUpdateURL": "/Home/UpdateData",
       "sAddURL": "/Home/AddData",
       "sDeleteURL": "/Home/DeleteData",
       "aoColumns": [{
               "sName": "ID",
               "bSearchable": false,
               "bSortable": false,
               "bVisible": false
           },
           { "sName": "Contact_Person" },
           { "sName": "Contact_Address" },
           { "sName": "Lead_Source" },
           { "sName": "Domain" },
           { "sName": "Sales_Person" },
           { "sName": "LeadName" }
       ]   

   }).****makeEditable({sUpdateURL: '/Home/UpdateData',
   sAddURL: '/Home/AddData',
   sDeleteURL: '/Home/DeleteData'});
   });****
```

In the above code Home/AjaxHandler IS FIRING ON load but below those i written some thing for edit, delete etc but those are not firing when i am trying to do anything.

My Work :

- WHILE ADDING : When i click on add popup is coming to add data later when i click it's saying Dependencies removed and also AddData not found
- WHILE EDITING/UPDATING : server not found error

I am confused and my controller crud methods are working perfectly i tested those manually

Any suggestions are appreciated 
Regards

Error Description :

**Description:** HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

```
    <b> Requested URL: </b>/AddData<br><br>
    <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

    <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Comment: i added code in makeEditable({ ... in above code . But now DELETE is working and break point in controller hitting but remaining edit and delete not working ?

Comment: Got the solution but still i didn't understand how i got :( Plugin issue i guess . Ty mates for your time and now me facing other issue possible refer my latest post . TY

Answer (score 0):

Your URL must be like this "/Home/UpdateData/".

Because parameter also append with URL.

Comment: You didn't shared your controller code. no problem 1. just check data table variable and action method variable name should be same.  2. Check your method should be HTTPGET .

Comment: humm ty some brilliant suggestions . Controller code i didn't share intentionally only as on delete button press , The code in controller not even hitting sadly ,  tested with a break point .

Comment: data table variable and action method variable name should be same ? i didn't get you exactly here . I written httpget on all methods in controller .